Jest Expect toBeCalledWith JSX.Element in function not Matching
We have an internal UI library that has function that renders the JSX.Element provided to it as parameter. Normally I would test this with React Testing Library but that is currently bugged. It works fine in the UI so I am just going to let the team who owns the library fix it. In the meantime as I wait for the fix, I mocked out the function but it's failing to match my expected JSX element. Any ideas?
React element:
import { toast } from '@company/alerts/toast'

export const ToastTest = ({title}: {title: string}) => {
   toast(<h1> {title} </h1>)

    return <div testId='toast-location-div'></div>
}


Test:
Import React from 'react'
import { ToastTest } from './toast-test'
import { toast } from '@company/alerts/toast'
import { render, waitFor } from 'react-testing-library'

jest.mock('@company/alerts', () => {
   ...jest.requireActual('@company/alerts'),
   toast: jest.fn()
}

const TestTitleComponent = ({title}) => <h1> {title} </h1>

describe('Toast test', () => {
   it('should call toast', async () => {
      render(<ToastTest title="foo" />

      await waitFor(() => {
         expect(toast).toHaveBeenCalledWith(<TestTitleComponent title="foo" />)
      }
   }
}

Error:
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)
    - Expected
    + Received

    - <h1> foo </h1>
    + <h1> foo </h1>

It seemed to get the exact same value but I think it's a reference error though I am not sure how to fix it.
Update:
I made it spy so I could get access to what the mock called like suggested in the comments. trying to see if the param is equal it gave the following error
  expect(toastSpy.mock.calls[0][0]).toStrictEqual(
         <h1> foo </h1>
       )
 
 Expected: <h1> foo </h1>
     Received: serializes to the same string

toBe, toMatchObject, and toEqual all provided the same error so I tried expect an object for both
  await waitFor(() => {
       expect(toastSpy).toHaveBeenCalled()
       expect(expect.objectContaining(toastSpy.mock.calls[0][0])).toEqual(
         expect.objectContaining(
           <h1> foo </h1>
         )
       )
     })

this gave big error showing the mock object had a lot more elements:
 Expected: ObjectContaining {"$$typeof": Symbol(react.element), "_owner": null, "_store": {}, "key": null, "props": {"tile": "foo"}, "ref": null, "type": [Function TestTitleComponent]}
     Received: ObjectContaining {"$$typeof": Symbol(react.element), "_owner": {"_debugHookTypes": [Array], "_debugNeedsRemount": false, "_debugOwner": null, "_debugSource": null, "actualDuration": 0, "actualStartTime": -1, "alternate": [FiberNode], "child": [FiberNode], "childLanes": 16, "deletions": null, "dependencies": null, "elementType": [Function MfaBannerToast], "flags": 8390657, "index": 0, "key": null, "lanes": 0, "memoizedProps": [Object], "memoizedState": [Object], "mode": 1, "pendingProps": [Object], "ref": null, "return": [FiberNode], "selfBaseDuration": 0, "sibling": null, "stateNode": null, "subtreeFlags": 14682629, "tag": 0, "treeBaseDuration": 0, "type": [Function TestTitleComponent], "updateQueue": [Object]}, "_store": {}, "key": null, "props": {"title": "foo"}, "ref": null, "type": [Function TestTitleComponent]}

which is weird but anyways  will just match on the props so I looked at the keys with Object.keys(). this gave me Received: [“$$typeof”, “type”, “key”, “ref”, “props”, “_owner”, “_store”]
so I tried .props
     src/banner/components/banner-toast.test.tsx:39:40 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'props'.
 
     39       expect(toastSpy.mock.calls[0][0]['props']).toEqual(

so I looked at object.values() and I found props on the 4th element and this worked but it's so hacky. There musts be a better way
 await waitFor(() => {
       expect(toastSpy).toHaveBeenCalled()
       expect(Object.values(toastSpy.mock.calls[0][0])[4]).toEqual({
         title: 'foo'
       })
     })


JSX is syntactic sugar for React.createElement() which returns an object. So yes, you are going to run into object reference equality issues trying to test like this.

I would question if there's really much value in this test.  What do you mean by I would test this with react-testing-library but that is currently bugged? Are you saying react testing library has a bug? What bug specifically?

No. Our internal toast library has a bug where if you have multiple tests in a file it doesn't render again in the next test. I simplified the component logic for this post but in the actual component there is a prop that has some user state to determine what the body text of the toast will be. In the actual test file I am trying to test that the toast function was called with the correct body text in few different user state scenarios

Just do .toHaveBeenCalled(), then grab what it was called with from the mock calls list and make separate assertions on that.

@jonrsharpe thanks for the suggestion. I changed it to spy so I could get the mock calls list. This I think lead me down the right direction but I am still running into issues. I updated the orginal post with some ramblings of what I discovered, hopefully that will help find a good solution.

expect(expect.objectContaining(toastSpy.mock.calls[0][0])). ...?! You want something like expect(render(toastSpy.mock.calls[0][0]).baseElement).toHaveTextContent(...);, surely.

@jonrsharpe thanks for the help. for some reason it thought toastSpy.mock.calls[0][0] was a string so I had to call it as render(toastSpy.mock.calls[0][0] as ReactElement)` but besides that it worked great. thanks for the suggestion. I wish there was better way but I think this will do for now
